# fopen with mode a does not set pointer to the end

Tags: php

I would expect this

```
$handle = fopen('file.txt', 'a');
var_dump(feof($handle));
```

To return true, as the mode 'a' sets the pointer at the end of the file. Instead it ouputs false.

Comment: `fopen()` returns false when there is an error. Does Apache have write access in the directory you are attempting to write in?

Comment: Yep, what is the output of `var_dump( $handle );`?

Comment: I checked with is_writable, which returns true. Does this perform different at your end?

Comment: var_dump($handle) returns: resource(5) of type (stream). Looks good to me.

Comment: I can confirm this problem. `ftell` reports `int(0)` in the code `$fHandle = fopen(SITE_PATH . "tests/csv1.csv", "a"); if ($fHandle !== false) { var_dump(ftell($fHandle)); }`.

Comment: ..that said, `fwrite` still **appends** to the file even though the file pointer is not placed at the end. After printing one character with `fwrite`, `ftell` reports `int(1)` which still is not the end of the file, but the character *was* added to the end and not the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feof()` doesn't tell you that you're at the end of the file *unless you performed a read operation to get there*. Since you can't read from an append-only file, `feof()` will never return true.